# Save Complex vector from Matlab to text file

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I generate a vector of complex numbers with Matlab and I want to save that vector into text file (.txt) to use it as input in my C code so the complex vectors looks like :

```
y = zeros(1,N);

for n = 1:N
    y(n) = exp(-1i*(n-1)*k*d*sind(Qtgt));
    
end
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQOHV.png)

 So I tried the functon dlmwrite to save the vector into text file :

```
dlmwrite('data.txt', y, 'delimiter','\n','newline', 'pc')
```

the vector stored like this :
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaeCl.png)

but I want it to be stored in this way :  [picture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm9tT.png)
every complex number should stored in new line and the real part, the imaginary part should be separated with coma 
 Any idea please ?

Comment: Does this work `writematrix([real(y).' + "," + imag(y).'] , 'data.txt' );`? (≥ R2019a)

Answer (score 1):

lifay:

This has a very simple fix: In your callout to `dlmwrite`, replace the `y` input for `[real(y'),imag(y')]`

Here's my attempt:

```
N = 10;
y = zeros(1,N);
for n = 1:N
    y(n) = exp(-1i*(n-1));
    re = real(y(n));
    im = imag(y(n));
    fprintf('%6.10f,%6.10f\n',re,im)
end
filename = 'output';
dlmwrite(filename,[real(y)',imag(y')],'precision',16)
```

Output to the above (granted I have a slightly different formula) on my end is:
[image]

The reason the output is given as shown by your "Picture 2" is that `y` is a row vector. Unless explicitly "told" otherwise by the programmer, MATLAB assumes arrays to be row vectors. MATLAB's `dlmwrite` output emulates the shape of the input array, in this case, a row vector, therefore, picture 2 is what you get. To get the output of picture 3, you must input a rectangular matrix. I achieve this above by concatenating two(2) row vectors that were transposed into column vectors. To perform the transposition use the `'` operator as shown. Notice that I transpose the output of the `real` function and then the input to the `imag` function. These functions also emulate the shape of their respective input arrays into their respective output arrays. So, `[real(y)',imag(y')]` has the same effect as `[real(y'),imag(y')]`.

Also, don't forget to specify the "precision" parameter to ensure that `dlmwrite` stores all the digits possible, if unspecified, `dlmwrite` will truncate the numbers and introduce truncation error into your further calculations in C.

Comment: Very nice answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you! Been meaning to reply but I unlocked the privilege much later. XD